# MySQL REGEXP Letters and numbers but no records of only numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

How do I `SELECT` all records with rows which the `value` column contains numbers *and* letters but *not* just numbers?

Let's say I have the following MySQL table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | a1    |
+----+-------+
| 2  | aa    |
+----+-------+
| 3  | 22    |
+----+-------+
| 4  | 3t    |
+----+-------+
```

The desired id rows returned would be 1, 2 and 4; not 3 because it only contains numbers.

Comment: What about punctuation?  Spaces?

Answer (score 2):

The `value/1` trick has a problem -- it only looks at digits at the start of `value`.

I think you need

```
WHERE `value` REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]'
  AND `value` REGEXP '[[:digit:]]'
```

or maybe

```
WHERE     `value` REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]'    -- contains letters
  AND NOT `value` REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$' -- but not just digits
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick without the need for any regular expressions.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (value / 1)='NULL';
```

Comment: No.  `'NULL'`, when treated as a number, is '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [value] REGEXP '[A-Za-z]' AND [value] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Ah, I suppose the examples I had seen where throwing extra things in to the regex. I tried this and it technically works though there are some records in this oddball table I'm working with that have values of just `0` that this didn't select compared to my version. So technically subjective to what someone needs, they have a choice! :-)